# Can django do computations in the client?

Tags: python, django, client-server

I am about to design an app that requires to do some medium level of computation (training some small machine learning model).

I am thinking about designing the app with django. Was wondering if django can allow that some of these computations can be done in the client‘s browser, i.e. using its memory and cpu. Some initial tips of where to start looking at will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does the client “run Django”? No - because it runs in Python on the server handling HTTP. However, the client might run, for example, JavaScript. Can JavaScript be used for “computations”? Yes. Can Django return/serve JavaScript? Yes. So, through proper collaboration *of different execution contexts*..

Comment: hey that´s very interesting. So you are suggesting to return a script from django that is run in the client, with all the calculations, isn´t it?

Comment: If the goal is that the client performs the calculations, the language/tool for said calculations must run on the client (whatever that is).

Comment: that´s clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's the reason Django is mostly used for building APIs.  If you want the View (Template in Django) to update, a request would be made to the server's Controller (View in Django) to render a new version of the webpage.  I would highly recommend a front end framework and just use Django for your api if you want to run client side computations.

Comment: Not sure I understand. So you are confirming that Django  can do the computation on the client side?

Comment: No the opposite.  Django sends data to the server to make computations and send a new render of the page.  That's why it is very inefficient for many types of applications.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And there is no way to reverse that with django? Do you know any framework to do that? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You would need to use Javascript and call views you made in Django.
You can use any javascript library, also Vue if you need a framework.